# Trouble accessing session data in Express/Redis after setting from Apollo Client mutation

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, next-auth

**Description:**

I'm working on a chat project using Next.js and Node.js, where I'm encountering an issue with session data not properly populating req.session on the server side after setting it from an Apollo Client mutation.

Upon a user sign-in using OAuth with NextAuth, I pass the session data to the server through an Apollo Client mutation like that:

```
  events: {
    async signIn({ user }: any) {
      const { PASS_SESSION_SERVER } = Operation.Mutations;

      await ApolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: PASS_SESSION_SERVER,
        variables: {
          sessionUser: {
            id: user.id,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
          },
        },
      });
    },
  },
```

**Server-side setup:**

```
const redisClient = createClient({
  url: "redis://localhost:6379",
  legacyMode: false,
});

redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Could not establish a connection with redis. " + err);
});
redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
  console.log("Connected to redis successfully");
});

redisClient.connect();

// =========== app use middlewares
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      client: redisClient,
      ttl(sess) {
        return 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
      },
    }),
    proxy: true,
    secret: "secretmeforever",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);
```

**Issue:**

After setting sessionUser in the req.session.user on the server-side using the Apollo GraphQL resolver, when I try to access req.session data in subsequent requests or routes, it only displays cookie details without the sessionUser data.

like that:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-12-17T07:05:21.693Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'none'
  }
}
```

but when I check the session on redis-cli (cmd), I get full user details, for example:

**cmd line**

```
get "sess:QYx3kKc7e_dyeCj3qLpr_vBTHvIlaJwV"

{
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge": 604800000,
    "expires": "2023-12-17T06:21:24.104Z",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "path": "/"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "657558e325a3f998e05212f",
    "email": "here is email",
    "name": "Davidname"
  }
}
```